# SimpleCursorAdapter throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, cursor

I found similar questions here but none of the solutions seem to work.

This is my custom adapter's constructor.

```
public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, 
    }
```

This is the activity that should populate the listview.

```
public class ContactList extends Activity {

    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public static final String[] from = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_PH_NO };

    public static final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textID, R.id.nameText,
            R.id.numberText };

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        Cursor cur = db.getAllContacts();

        ContactAdapter adapter = new ContactAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list, cur, from, to);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

It throws a null pointer exception. Here is my stack tree.

```
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.example.databaseproject/com.example.databaseproject.ContactList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at com.example.databaseproject.ContactList.onCreate(ContactList.java:42)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    08-12 11:39:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(6902):     ... 11 more
```

Please ask if any other code sample is required to trace the issue.

PS: I checked the database that gets created. It has values(it is not empty).
If I comment this line it doesn't throw the error.

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `NullPointerException` in this line `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` becouse you dont initiate or bind the `listView`. It must be null. so its impossible to call `setAdapter` on it.

Do at least this to bind it:

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);
```

inside the onCreate method.

Comment: Mistakes are part of our business :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a member variable `ListView listView;` that was never initialized and therefore contains `null` value. I think that `NullPointerException` is self explainable enough.

To avoid this you have to create instance of `ListView` and assign it to your member `listView` exactly as you did for strings and arrays `from` and `to`.